# Is there a way to reorganise pixels in an image from darkest to brightest in Gimp?

Tags: image, pixel, gimp

I do a lot of Zoom quizzes, and am always looking for new and interesting rounds to include. Recently I saw a screenshot of a quiz where someone had taken album covers and rearranged the colours in the image so that all the darkest colours were in the top left and there was a smooth gradient to the lightest colours in the bottom right.

I am basically looking for a way to do this myself. Is there a tool on Gimp that will allow me to rearrange all the pixels by their colour value in a smooth gradient? I'm not tied to Gimp and would be open to trying other programs that could do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a before/after exemple?

Comment: @xenoid This is an example where each row of the album cover of Robyn's Honey album has been sorted from light to dark, what I'm looking to do is sort the entire image light to dark https://imgur.com/aEQuyxK

Comment: No such tool in Gimp. It wouldn't be too hard to code, load the image, associate to each RGB triplet it's luminosity, sort the triplet by luminosity, save the image. Plenty of libraries to load/save the image, in Python look at the `pillow` library for image I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Will have a play around